# how to post multiple data to rest api

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart

when ever I try to post list of data at one time to rest api the api deletes the previous data and stares new one

```
[
    {
        "name": "6E72Ln9Y095x8n80Xgk6\/435291346914161.jpg",
        "class": "APKZZX",
        "email": "2142103j983H1",
        "roll_number": "6E72Ln9Y095x8n80Xgk6",
        "password": "2023-02-27 21:25:50.347756",
        "image": "",
        "role": "student",
        "school_id": "2142103j983H1",
        "id": "734506"
    },
    {
        "name": "6E72Ln9Y095x8n80Xgk6\/435291346914161.jpg",
        "class": "APKZZX",
        "email": "2142103j983H1",
        "roll_number": "6E72Ln9Y095x8n80Xgk6",
        "password": "2023-02-27 21:25:50.347756",
        "image": "",
        "role": "student",
        "school_id": "2142103j983H1",
        "id": "734506"
    }
]
```

this is my json data and my flutter code is here

```
  upload() async {
    try {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? schoolId = prefs.getString('school_id');
      var map = {};
      List maps = List.empty(growable: true);
      Users user = Users();
      var value = data.skip(1).toList();
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        user = Users(
          name: value[i][0].toString(),
          class1: value[i][1].toString(),
          email: value[i][2].toString(),
          roll_number: value[i][3].toString(),
          password: value[i][4].toString(),
          image: '',
          role: 'student',
          school_id: schoolId.toString(),
          id: randomAlphaNumeric(6),
        );
      }
      value.forEach((element) {
        Db.post('users', user.toJson());
      });
      print(user.toJson().toString());
      EasyLoading.showSuccess(user.toJson().toString());
    } catch (e) {
      EasyLoading.showError('Khalad ayaa jira fadlan hubi oo ku celi');
    }
  }
```

if any one has solution. that I can post multiple data once on my api or posting it one by one.